# Why do we have std::string::npos but no std::vector::npos?

Tags: c++, containers, std

I would like to use -1 to indicate a size that has not yet been computed:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> sizes(nResults, -1);
```

and I was wondering why isn't there a more expressive way:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> sizes(nResults, std::vector<std::size_t>::npos);
```

Comment: std::string is  just weird. It has far too many members and is too weird. The real question is why string isn't more like vector. (The answer is probably C.)

Comment: I would think it is because most everything with vectors deals with iterators where string functions return positions.

Comment: `vector` has no `find`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Wasn't `std::string` initially created before the STL and then the STL side tacked on later?

Comment: @chris: I'm not sure, but that sounds highly plausible. A string class would be the first obvious exercise in any context.

Comment: `npos` is pretty much a replacement for `.end()` as an index instead of an iterator. `std::vector` has no index-based functions, so it doesn't make sense that there would be an end/invalid index.

Comment: As far as a more expresive way why not `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` or if you really want to go all out `std::numeric_limits<std::vector<whatever_type>::size_type>::max()`?

Comment: I suppose you can define your own special constant like: `const std::size_t none = -1;`

Comment: Why should a special value for `size_t` have anything to do with `std::vector` ? Your vector stores `size_t` values, not other vectors.  You could write `const size_t noncomputed = -1;` if you think that makes your code more readable.

Comment: @chris - yes, `std::string` predated the addition of the STL. Uwe Steinmüller and I designed the original version (which included `npos`), and many people stepped on it after that.

Comment: @PeteBecker, Oh, that's cool to know, thanks!

Comment: I would say that the semantic equivalence of `npos` to `NULL` for functions like `string::find` _vs_ their C ancestors like `strstr` and `strchr` could have made it much more attractive for C programmers to adopt C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t):

> std::size_t is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof
>   operator as well as the sizeof operator and the alignof operator
>   (since C++11)....
>
> ...std::size_t can store the maximum size of a
>   theoretically possible object of any type...

`size_t` is unsigned, and can't represent -1.  In reality if you were to attempt to set your sizes to -1, you would actually be setting them to the maximum value representable by a `size_t`.

Therefore you should not use `size_t` to represent values which include the possible size of a type in addition to a value indicating that no size has been computed, because any value outside the set of possible sizes can not be represented by a `size_t`.

You should use a different type which is capable of expressing all of the possible values you wish to represent.  Here is one possibility:

```
struct possibly_computed_size_type
{
    size_t size;
    bool is_computed;
};
```

Of course, you'll probably want a more expressive solution than this, but the point is that at least `possibly_computed_size_type` is capable of storing all of the possible values we wish to express.

One possibility is to use an `optional` type.  An `optional` type can represent the range of values of a type, and an additional value meaning 'the object has no value'.  [The boost library provides such a type.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

The standard library also provides an optional type as an experimental feature.  Here is an example I created using this type:
http://ideone.com/4J0yfe

Comment: -1. Note that std::string::npos is defined as `((std::size_t)(-1))` so there is prior art. Instead of designating a single value as a "special value," which is completely reasonable, you recommend wasting additional bytes!

Answer (score 8):

It basically comes down to a fairly simple fact: `std::string` includes searching capability, and that leads to a requirement for telling the caller that a search failed. `std::string::npos` fulfills that requirement.

`std::vector` doesn't have any searching capability of its own, so it has no need for telling a caller that a search has failed. Therefore, it has no need for an equivalent of `std::string::npos`.

The standard algorithms do include searching, so they do need to be able to tell a caller that a search has failed. They work with iterators, not directly with collections, so they use a special iterator (one that should never be dereferenced) for this purpose. As it happens, `std::vector::end()` returns an iterator suitable for the purpose, so that's used--but this is more or less incidental. It would be done without (for example) any direct involvement by `std::vector` at all.