# Why does `std::string::find()` not return the end iterator on failures?

Tags: c++, stdstring, std

I find the behaviour of `std::string::find` to be inconsistent with standard C++ containers.

E.g.

```
std::map<int, int> myMap = {{1, 2}};
auto it = myMap.find(10);  // it == myMap.end()
```

But for a string,

```
std::string myStr = "hello";
auto it = myStr.find('!');  // it == std::string::npos
```

Why shouldn't the failed `myStr.find('!')` return `myStr.end()` instead of `std::string::npos`?

Since the `std::string` is somewhat special when compared with other containers, I am wondering whether there is some real reason behind this. 
(Surprisingly, I couldn't find anyone questioning this anywhere).

Comment: I think only reasonable answer is close to answer to question: 'Why are hotdogs packed in 4 and hotdog buns in 6?' Well, it's the way the world happend to be

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35443953/5517378)

Comment: IMHO, a reason for this behavior would be that `std::string` internally consists of characters which are inexpensive elements (in regard of memory). And, furthermore, character is the only type `std::string` can contain. On the other hand, `std::map` consists of more complex elements. Also, specification of `std::map::find` says that it is supposed to find an element, and specification of `std::string::find` says that it's task is to find position.

Comment: For map, you can’t have an npos iterator so the end iterator is used.  For string, we can use npos, so why not :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To begin with, the `std::string` interface is well known to be bloated and inconsistent, see Herb Sutter's [Gotw84](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) on this topic. But nevertheless, there is a reasoning behind `std::string::find` returning an index: `std::string::substr`. This convenience member function operates on indices, e.g.

```
const std::string src = "abcdefghijk";

std::cout << src.substr(2, 5) << "\n";
```

You could implement `substr` such that it accepts iterators into the string, but then we wouldn't need to wait long for loud complaints that `std::string` is unusable and counterintuitive. So given that `std::string::substr` accepts indices, how would you find the index of the first occurence of `'d'` in the above input string in order to print out everything starting from this substring?

```
const auto it = src.find('d'); // imagine this returns an iterator

std::cout << src.substr(std::distance(src.cbegin(), it));
```

This might also not be what you want. Hence we can let `std::string::find` return an index, and here we are:

```
const std::string extracted = src.substr(src.find('d'));
```

If you want to work with iterators, use `<algorithm>`. They allow you to the above as

```
auto it = std::find(src.cbegin(), src.cend(), 'd');

std::copy(it, src.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

Comment: Good point. However, instead of returning an iterator, `std::string::find` could still return `size()`, instead of `npos`, retaining compatibility with `substr`, while also avoiding several extra brances.

Comment: @erenon Maybe, but `std::string::substr` already covers the "start here until the end" case with a default parameter for the second index (`npos`). I guess returning `size()` would also be confusing and having a literal sentinel like `npos` might be the better choice?!

Comment: @lubgr But if `std::string::find` returns an iterator, `std::string::substr` would probably also accept an iterator for the start position. Your example with find would look the same in both cases in this alternate world.

Comment: @MattiasWallin Good point. But `std::string::substr` with an iterator argument opens the door for one further UB case (besides the past-the-end scenario that can equally well happen with indices or iterators): passing an iterator that refers to another string.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `std::string` have two interfaces:

- The general **iterator** based interface found on all containers
- The `std::string` specific **index** based interface

`std::string::find` is part of the **index** based interface, and therefore returns indices.

Use `std::find` to use the general iterator based interface.

Use `std::vector<char>` if you don't want the index based interface (don't do this).